# Troubleshooting a photo that will view but not save

Tags: windows-7, picasa

I kept getting a general error while uploading photos to a [photo book website](http://www.mixbook.com).

So I tried [another service](http://photobucket.com/) and this time I got a specific error ("IMP error") on one of the pics.

If I try to open this photo in paint, I get this error:

> D:\MyDocuments\My Pictures\a14.jpg
>
> Paint cannot read this file.
>
> This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently
>   supported.

If I try to edit it in Picasa, I get this error:

> Unable to to write redeye due to a disk error.  The disk may be full
>   or read-only.

Despite these errors, I can VIEW the photo in Picasa; plus, Windows 7 was able to make a thumbnail of the pic.

I circumvented the problem by using **Prt Scr**, crop the desktop to just the image being viewed and then saving that as the image.  That's lame though.

Is there anyway I can troubleshoot/repair an image that can be viewed but not altered?

[Here is a direct link](http://www.o1solution.com/a14.jpg) to the image.

One note to make about this image is that it is almost 6 times bigger (31mb) than the other photos in the set.